# Provide strong consistency in Redis Cluster

Tags: redis, synchronization, redis-cluster

I need to load static data one time in redis in the master node and only when the synchronization is finished for all slaves I am going to be able to read. This is because we are going to have a lot reading and a few writing, and the data is not going to change for a long time.

I read from oficial documentation https://docs.redis.com/latest/rs/concepts/data-access/consistency-durability/, https://docs.redis.com/latest/rs/concepts/data-access/consistency-durability/ and https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial in Redis Cluster consistency guarantees.

I read also [Can the WAIT command provide strong consistency in Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629339/can-the-wait-command-provide-strong-consistency-in-redis) but without to get a conclusion.

If I use synchronous replication and wait command to check if the replication was successful, do I have some guarantees about consistency ?

Answer (score 2):

By default, a Redis Cluster is not able to guarantee **strong consistency**. It means that under certain conditions it is possible that Redis Cluster will lose writes that were acknowledged by the system to the client.

The reason why Redis Cluster can lose writes is because it uses asynchronous replication, however, you can improve consistency by forcing the database to flush data to disk before replying to the client, but this usually results in prohibitively **low performance**. That would be the equivalent of synchronous replication in the case of Redis Cluster. Basically, there is a trade-off to be made between performance and consistency, if you are fine with that!

Redis Cluster has support for synchronous writes when absolutely needed, implemented via the [WAIT](https://redis.io/commands/wait) command. This makes losing writes a lot less likely. However, note that Redis Cluster does not implement strong consistency even when synchronous replication is used: it is always possible, under more complex failure scenarios, that a replica that was not able to receive the write will be elected as master.

There is another notable scenario where Redis Cluster will lose writes, that happens during a network partition where a client is isolated with a minority of instances including at least a master.

For example, imagine a 6 nodes cluster composed of A, B, C, A1, B1, C1, with 3 masters and 3 replicas. There is also a client, let's call it Z1.

After a partition occurs, it is possible that in one side of the partition we have A, C, A1, B1, C1, and in the other side we have B and Z1.

Z1 is still able to write to B, which will accept its writes. If the partition heals in a very short time, the cluster will continue normally. However, if the partition lasts enough time for B1 to be promoted to master on the majority side of the partition, the writes that Z1 has sent to B in the meantime will be lost.

Note that there is a **maximum window** to the amount of writes Z1 will be able to send to B: if enough time has elapsed for the majority side of the partition to elect a replica as master, every master node in the minority side will have stopped accepting writes.

This amount of time is a very important configuration directive of Redis Cluster, and is called the **node timeout**.

After node timeout has elapsed, a master node is considered to be failing, and can be replaced by one of its replicas. Similarly, after node timeout has elapsed without a master node to be able to sense the majority of the other master nodes, it enters an error state and stops accepting writes.

Comment: if I avoid the cluster, am I goint to be able to guarantee consitency ? wich is the best way  to guarantee consistency with Redis ? Redis is a wonderful tool but in my case I need to be accurate I need the consistency and in second place performance.

Comment: If you avoid a cluster, of course you can avoid the inconsistencies that may happen but then you are not using Redis database to its full potential and not scaling it. Maybe take a look at the CAP Theorem and why there's no 100% consistency guarantee in distributed systems: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem

Comment: There are some ways that you can manually control the consistency in Redis with `WAIT` command. For example with `WAIT` command you can enforce that previous writes are successfully transferred and acknowledged by at least the specified number of replicas. Although `WAIT` doesn't guarantee the data is written in all required replicas but it will return you, how many replicas confirmed the write. If it's less than your desired threshold, then you can handle that situation in your application code.